# Calculate velocity of a ping pong ball launcher

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, projectile, drag

I'm trying to create a ping pong ball launcher based on the design of the common tennis ball launcher which consists of two rotating circular discs which rotate in opposite directions, when a ball is sent through the two discs it gets accelerated forward with a higher velocity. I'm using two toy car tires of dimensions (2x47x11mm) with rubber outer surface and two motors of 5500 rpm each. Based on this how can I calculate the maximum velocity the ball will achive?Also, how does air drag play a role on the final velocity?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of factors involved here. Since the ping pong balls follow a circular track with a known rpm one could use centripetal force to calculate the launch velocity. But that is just theoretical. There is friction on the balls from the rubber, which is not so easily determined.

The best way is to measure by experiment. If you can determine the angle the ball is launched from is good, but hard to do with precision. Best way is to launch the
balls horizontally from a certain height and measure the time it takes a ball to reach the ground.

Air drag should have little effect if the balls only travel a couple of meters,
but you could look up the drag coefficient for a spherical shape and add that to
your calculations.

Another way is to have a tool that can register force and you can get the speed from the force of impact just as the ball leaves the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of the outer rim of the tyres $v$ is found by multiplying the radius $r$ by the angular speed in radians per second $\omega$.

$5500$ rpm is $5500/60 = 91.67$ revolutions per second (that seems very high to me) which is $91.67 \times 2\pi =576$ radians per second. I am going to assume the diameter of each tyre is $47$ mm, so its radius is $23.5$ mm. So we have

$v =r\omega = 23.5 \times 576 = 13535$ mm/s

which is just over $13.5$ metres per second, or about $30$ miles per hour.

This is the maximum speed at which the rotating tyres can propel a ping pong ball. But ping pong balls are so light and non-aerodynamic that air drag will quickly slow them down. So I doubt you will see anything like $30$ mph in practice.

Comment: Does having two tyres make a difference in the speed? How much will air drag affect the velocity?